How to configure job yaml and Yolov8 dataset ymal to access data asset on Azure?
I am currently training a custom model using Yolov8 in Azure ML studio using Azure ML CLI v2.
Issue:
When I run the job on Azure ML, I am getting Permission Denied error
Error Code: ScriptExecution.StreamAccess.Authentication
Native Error: error in streaming from input data sources
    StreamError(PermissionDenied(Some(This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)))
=> permission denied when access stream. Reason: Some(This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)
    PermissionDenied(Some(This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.))
Error Message: Authentication failed when trying to access the stream. Make sure you have correct permissions set up. Ok(This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.)| session_id=da7b713c-6cc8-4f6d-b24f-b54ab37e14ef

Yaml files:

job.yaml:

$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/commandJob.schema.json
experiment_name: yolov8-experiment

command: |
  sed -i "s|path:.*$|path: ${{ inputs.training_data }}|" custom_dataset.yaml
  # Train the model
  yolo task=detect train data=custom_dataset.yaml model=${{ inputs.model_to_train }} epochs=10 project=yolov8-experiment name=experiment

inputs:
  training_data:
    type: uri_folder 
    mode: ro_mount
    path: azure:data_asset:1 #I have created the data asset from the files in my local.
  model_to_train:
    type: custom_model
    path: azureml:yolov8l:1

code: /training-code/ #path where the custom_dataset.yaml is stored in local
environment: azureml:yolov8-environment:1
compute: azureml:compute_cluster


custom_dataset.yaml file:

path: ../dataset
train: /images/train/
test: /images/test/
val: /images/test/

nc=2

# class names
names:[class1, class2]

I have used theses articles for reference:
Medium-article-yolov8-training-azure-cli
Training Models on Azure ML with CLI v2 - Microsoft Training
I am facing issues determining the necessary permissions to proceed with my Azure setup. I have successfully signed in using 'az login' and have managed to create various components such as the environment, compute cluster, and data asset.
However, I am unsure about the specific permissions required to proceed further. What permissions need to be granted for my setup to function properly?

Check your  azureml:compute_cluster is having necessary permission on your input training data.

The workspace in which I have create the compute cluster is assigned to the
Storage Blob Data Contributor role. Do I have to assign the role to the cluster too?

If you are using service principal or managed identity  in cluster for authorization you may need give permission.

Default it will be using managed identity i guess. so you need to assign the Storage Blob Data Contributor role. to it

Actually you will get syntactical error for the dataset custom_dataset.yaml. i don't know how you are getting permission related error.
